# Cannot read property of undefined React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks

I am trying to create a search feature using react hooks but it keeps returning the error:

> Cannot read Property of Undefined

on the `updateSearch` function whenever I type in the input field.

```
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState([]);

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    open: false,
    name: '',
    users:[]
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllUsers();
  }, []);


  const getAllUsers = () => {
    fetch('/userinformation/', { 
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    }).then(function(body) {
      console.log(body);
      setState({...state, users: body });
    })
  }

  const updateSearch = (event) => {
   setSearch(event.target.value)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const results = state.users.filter(user =>
      user.toLowerCase().includes(search)
    );
    setSearchResults(results);
  }, [search]);

return (
<input type="text" value={search} onChange={(e) => updateSearch(e.target.value)}/>
)
```

Whenever I type in the search bar I get the following error:
 [image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either get to the value of passed event by changing

```
<input type="text" value={search} onChange={(event) => updateSearch(event}/>
```

or you can keep the input element as it is and change the update updateSearch callback to

```
const updateSearch = (event) => { setSearch(event) }
```

Secondly, you are applying includes to a single item of an array which is specific to array methods, you need to make following changes as well to make it work:

```
React.useEffect(() => { 
 const results = state.users.filter( user => user.firstName.toLowerCase() === search ); 
 setSearchResults(results); 
}, [search])
```

Comment: This fixes that error now I get an error on the second useEffect saying user.toLowerCase is not a function. Do you know why this is occuring? In the state I can access the user array.

Comment: you applying includes on a single string value. Includes works on arrays only. You can find the relevant examples at this link: 

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes**

Comment: I think this would work:

`React.useEffect(() => {
    const results = state.users.filter(user =>
      user.toLowerCase() === search
    );
    setSearchResults(results);
  }, [search]);`

Answer (score 1):

in your input you're already passing value`onChange={(e) => updateSearch(e.target.value)` and in `updateSearch` you're trying to accessing it. Change it like this, if you want to access `event` in `updateSearch` method and get value from it.

```
<input type="text" value={search} onChange={(e) => updateSearch(e}/>
```

Comment: This fixes that error now I get an error on the second useEffect saying user.toLowerCase is not a function. Do you know why this is occuring? In the state I can access the user array.

Comment: user is of which type ? is it a `string/array`. i see you mentioning it as an user array `.toLowerCase` wont work on an array

Answer (score 1):

You have already passed the value of the input into the `updateSearch` method.

This is how you should fix it:

```
const updateSearch = (value) => {
   setSearch(value);
};
```

And as for the second issue you have raised on your `useEffect` hook, you will have to call `toLowerCase()` on one of your properties (either `firstName` or `lastName`), depending on what you need to search for.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const results = state.users.filter(user =>
    user.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(search)
  );
  setSearchResults(results);
}, [search]);
```

Comment: This fixes that error now I get an error on the second useEffect saying user.toLowerCase is not a function. Do you know why this is occuring? In the state I can access the user array.

Comment: @EzJS can you console.log() your state? And post a sample of the response over here.

Comment: The user state looks like this.0: {id: 1, firstName: "Elton", lastName: "Frederick", departmentId: 1, admin: true, …}
1: {id: 2, firstName: "Erwing", lastName: "Hernandez", departmentId: 10, admin: true, …}
2: {id: 3, firstName: "Web Development", lastName: "", departmentId: 0, admin: true, …} I believe the issue is i cannot use .toLowerCase on an array

Comment: @EzJS do you want to lowercase the firstname or the lastname?

Comment: I want to lowercase the firstname

Comment: @EzJS in that case, my updated answer should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I would teach you a secret that has worked very well for me over the years. When javascript gives you such error as `cannot read property ***whateverValue*** value of undefined` it means you are trying to read the property of an object that does not exist. In this case, the object you're trying to read from is `undefined`, hence it cannot have any `key: value` pair.

Back to your question: `TypeError: Cannot read property value of undefined`

1. Using `cmd+f` to check for all places where value is used shows me everywhere you used `value` on `event.target.value`

Stay with me (I know this is boring, but it would help later).

2. You have an event handler named `updateSearch`.
3. All you need here now is to change your input tag to this:

`<input type="text" value={search} onChange={updateSearch}/>`
Don't worry, React would handle the rest, it automatically parses the event to eventHandler which can then be accessed on such eventHandler.

Also, I think you might want to refactor this component.

Something like `import React, {useState, useEffect} from React`
you won't have to call `React.useEffect` or `React.useState` in other parts of the project. just `useEffect` or `useState`.
Goodluck :+1